Prometheus: how to calculate memory usage for all nodes with wildcard
I am calculating the memory utilization efficiency for all the nodes of my Kubernetes cluster. The metrics are collected by Node Exporter. I want a single number in the end to represent the average efficiency of the whole cluster during last 24 hours.
With Prometheus, I can get the "instant" value for a single node with the query like (where node filter is exactly the node name):
    100 -
    (
      avg(node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{jobLabel="node-exporter", node="aks-spot-62019936-vmss0000j5"})
    /
      avg(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{jobLabel="node-exporter", node="aks-spot-62019936-vmss0000j5"})
    * 100
    )

However, it can't return a single value if I change the node filter to a like operator as the following:
100 -
(
  avg(node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{jobLabel="node-exporter", node=~"aks-spot-.*"})
/
  avg(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{jobLabel="node-exporter", node=~"aks-spot-.*"})
* 100
)

The strange thing is that, if I change the filter to : node=~"aks-linux-.*" which is the nodes in the AKS node pool whose number doesn't change.
Also, if I change to use "range" query, instead of "instant" query, it works.
Could you tell me why and how it comes ? How to achieve my objectif please ?
Thanks a lot

I tested the same on another cluster, with the wildcard filter, it works well. What could be the reason ? Is there a fix for that ?

I'm not sure I understand you problem here. Does "it can't return a single value" means no values returned, on to many values?

Also combination of "during last 24 hours", instant query and function avg doesn't make much sence for me. Were you intending to use avg_over_time, od do I miss you point?

To achieve the aggregation across all nodes with a wildcard, you need to group the results by the label that you want to aggregate over. However, since you want a single number representing the entire cluster, you should not group by the node label at all; instead, you should aggregate all the results together.
Here is the correct query that calculates the average memory utilization across all matching nodes for the last 24 hours:
100 * (1 - (
  sum(avg_over_time(node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job="node-exporter", instance=~"10\\.224\\.\\d+\\.\\d+:9100"}[24h]))
  / 
  sum(avg_over_time(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{job="node-exporter", instance=~"10\\.224\\.\\d+\\.\\d+:9100"}[24h]))
))


here,

avg_over_time() calculates the average of each time series in the vector over the last 24 hours.
sum() then adds up all the averages to get a cluster-wide total for available and total memory.
The ratio of the sum of MemAvailable to MemTotal is then computed, subtracted from 1 to get the utilization, and finally multiplied by 100 to convert to a percentage.
By not specifying a group by clause, the sum() function aggregates across all nodes, ignoring the individual node labels.

The reason you might not be able to get a single value with a wildcard pattern in the node label is that the avg function without a group modifier computes the average across all elements in a vector. When you use a pattern match in the node label, you're creating a vector with multiple elements (one for each node that matches the pattern), and Prometheus doesn't implicitly aggregate across these different series because it treats each series with a distinct node label as unique.
References:

Query Prometheus metrics using the API and PromQL

